# CakePHP - Writing to 2 db tables from the same view

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to write a small expenses cake app. Basicaly I have a expenseClaim that hasMany Expenses (expense belongsTo expenseClaim). When you add/edit a expenseClaim I want to be able to add multiple expenses for that expense claim from within that view. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Any tutorials / sample code would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance

*using cake 2.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in expenseClaim/add:

```
$this->expenseClaim->Expense->create();
```

It should work if the relationship is well set in the model.

If not,

```
$this->loadModel('Expense');
 $this->Expense->create();
```

should always work.

Edit:

```
$data=array
    (
        [Expense] => Array
        (
            [fieldname1] => 'value'
            [fieldname2] => 'value'
        )
    )



 $this->loadModel('Expense');
 $this->Expense->create();
            if ($this->Expense->save($data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Done.'));

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Failure.'));
            }
```

Edit2: if you want to pass data from the view:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                    $this->loadModel('Expense');

        $this->Expense->create();
        if ($this->Expense->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Done.'));

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Failure'));
        }
    }
```

The request is created automatically if you use the form helper in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, wuld you mind expanding a little on your code. So, for example, how would I tell it what data goes into the relevant expense fields?

Comment: Ah ok, I follow, thank you - one last question (sorry!) would I have to hard code this in my view? For example (in view) 

<input name="data[Expense][sitename]" type="text" id="ExpenseSitename">

or is there another more cakey way?

Thanks again

Comment: Ah easier than I thought! Would this work if I wwanted to created multiple expenses (db rows) in the same save?

Comment: You could either do a loop (easier) or use saveMany: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: Thank you for all your help, cake is slowly beginning to make much more sense!

Comment: Sorry - as I'm creating the expense within the expense claim so do I need to do $this->ExpenseClaim->save($this->request->data AND $this->Expense->save($this->request->data) ??